# Luis endpoint is showing different results when published

Tags: azure, nlp, azure-language-understanding

My luis end point is giving different results after publishing. The output from the testing is not same as the published app.

Check out the result i am getting (image)

[image: 1]

Comment: Please provide more information about the actual output and the expected result

Comment: The image you posted makes it look like you're comparing one utterance before publishing with a totally different utterance after publishing. Did you mean to do that?

Comment: @ Panciz  @Kyle Delaney  Thank you for your response. I have found the issue. My test utterance had '&' in it and when it gets passed to the endpoint , it will truncate the sentences after the '&' symbol.

Comment: Would you like you post that as an answer so you can mark this question as answered?